# unlock InputStream Java

Tags: java, multithreading, synchronization, inputstream

I have these two threads: t1 and t2. t1 is always listening to messages from the server, but t2 is only notified when a message is sent. The reason to lock ObjectInputStream is that the message waits for confirmation of recipient and message-id.

The question: why does t1 never release the lock on ois?

**t1 method**

```
public void run() {
    Object o;
    while (!Thread.interrupted()) {
        try {
            synchronized (ois) {
                System.out.println("t1: locked ois");
                o = ois.readObject();
            }
            System.out.println("t1: unlocked ois");
            if (o.getClass().isAssignableFrom(Model.Message.class)) {
                receiveMessage((Message) o);
            }
            if (o.getClass().isAssignableFrom(ArrayList.class)) {
                updateUsers((ArrayList<Model.User>) o);
            }
        } catch (EOFException e) {
            System.out.println("stopped");
            t2.stop();
            t1.stop();
        } catch (IOException | ClassNotFoundException e) {
            try {
                Thread.sleep(1000);
            } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
                ex.printStackTrace();
            }
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

**t2 method**

```
public void run() {
        while (!Thread.interrupted()) {
            try {
                Message currMessage = messageBuffer.get();
                System.out.println("t2: waiting to lock ois");
                synchronized (ois) {
                    System.out.println("t2: locked ois");
                    oos.writeObject(currMessage);
                    oos.flush();
                    int currID = -1;
                    while (currID < 0) {
                        currID = ois.readInt();
                        currMessage.setCurrId(currID);
                    }
                }
            } catch(IOException | InterruptedException e){
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        }
    }
}
```

**The buffer that regulates t2**

```
public class Buffer<T> implements Serializable {
private static final long serialVersionUID = -5886308724572898536L;
private LinkedList<T> buffer = new LinkedList<T>();

public synchronized void put(T obj) {
    buffer.addLast(obj);
    notifyAll();
}

public synchronized T get() throws InterruptedException {
    while(buffer.isEmpty()) {
        wait();
    }
    return buffer.removeFirst();
}

public int size() {
    return buffer.size();
}
}
```

The output

```
t1: locked ois
t2: waiting to lock ois
```

Comment: Because you never receive an object?

Comment: I added the buffer class. The print "t2: waiting to lock ois"  wouldn't run if it didn't receive any object. But i guess you're talking about t1 and in that case, yeah that is true that it doesn't receive any objects. I want t1 to run continuously despite not receiving anything, but when t2 is activated, I want them to synchronize on the usage of ObjectInputStream.

Comment: But while t1 is waiting for objects to come along it holds on to the lock, so t2 can't do its work in that case.

Comment: I want t1 to run continuously, listening for objects from a server on another computer. I don't know if there is a more effective way to notify it only when the server wants to send data, because the server is not on the same computer so its only input is through this stream.

Comment: how do I make t1 unlock ois if no objects come along, but only for a second to allow t2 to take lock (if t2 activated); otherwise, it just repeats the process (if t2 inactive -  waiting)

Comment: i tried adding a sleep or wait after an objects was attempted to be read, but it doesn't unlock the inputstream. synchronized (ois) {
                    System.out.println("t1: locked ois");
                    o = ois.readObject();
                    while(o == null){
                        ois.wait(500);
                        Thread.sleep(500);
                    }
                }